# Search bar not visible on mount with the native stack in react-navigation on IOS?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

Search bar not visible with the native stack in react-navigation on IOS?

Android is working fine but I'm having issues with IOS.

I want the scrollbar to disappear on scrolling down so I have

```
hideWhenScrolling: true
```

The problem is that the scrollbar starts hidden.

I want to make the scrollbar start visible OR have an icon the user can press to display the search bar.

As it is users may not be able to find the search bar.

I have tried a bunch of options, create a buttons with state changes that should make the scrollbar exist/undefined, I've tried to move the creation outside the header and rather be on useLayoutEffect but nothing is working.

Comment: No :(  Please come back if you do

Comment: Sure thing. An issue was already raised for this but was closed as they didn't provide adequate info: https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/10848